# Reformatting two-digit year in Stata from string to date-time using top-year

Tags: stata

I understand to translate the strings 01-12-06 AND 01-12-96 as dates in Stata, you must:

- specify the assumed prefix in the mask, "DM20Y" and
- add an optional argument topyear: clock(string, mask, topyear)

So, `generate double timestamp = clock(timestr, "DMY", 2020)` makes the two-digit year 06 interpreted as 2006 because 2006 does not exceed 2020. The two-digit year 96 would be interpreted as 1996 because 2096 does exceed 2020.

But, I'm having trouble implementing this. So, instead I decided to:

```
g date = date(strdate, "MD20Y")
format date %td
```

Then I want to basically replace dates greater than 2040 with the prefix "19" (so 2097 becomes 1997; but 2006 stays 2006).

Can somebody please tell me how to write that conditional statement? I keep getting errors.

Or, conversely, how do I use the `topyear` functionality correctly?

Answer (score 3):

The function `date()` yields numeric daily dates from string arguments, given a rule for interpreting them. It dates from [pun intended] the earliest introduction of date functions in Stata 4 in 1995, when daily dates were the only kind specially supported, calendar years being considered self-explanatory. Now the synonym `daily()` is available and I suggest could and should be used instead, regardless of how well informed your readership is on Stata arcana. Otherwise, as quite often happens, people may start guessing that `date()` is a general-purpose function that yields other kinds of date according to the whim of the user, contrary to all documentation on the point.

In terms of your question, I think all that you need to know further is that `daily()` and `date()` support topyear specification. Examples:

```
. di  %td daily("24 May 96", "DMY", 2050)
24may1996

. di %td daily("24 May 06", "DMY", 2050)
24may2006
```

Meta-tip: I always test date problems with `display` and specific examples where (I think) I know what the answer should be.

Documentation from `help daily()` in Stata or [here](http://www.stata.com/help.cgi?daily())

Comment: Yes! Thank you. That was so quick.